# What is the public spend key used for?

Tags: viewkey

I know if you give your public **view key** to someone, they can see all the **incoming** transactions to an address. But it does not show the output transactions of that address. Is this what the **public spend key** is for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The public view key doesn't allow seeing the incoming transactions. The private view key does that.

In fact, the public view key and public spend key are contained in the Monero address you give to people so that they can send you funds.

The public spend key is used (together with the public view key) to generate the public key of an output.

To generate the private key of an output (to spend it or to generate its key image to check if it has been spent), you need the private view key and the private spend key of the wallet.

Check [What significance does the wallet public spendkey and public viewkey have in a transaction?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/what-significance-does-the-wallet-public-spendkey-and-public-viewkey-have-in-a-t?rq=1) for more details on how the public and private keys of an output are generated.

Comment: So the private spend key would let me see outgoing transactions? Can I give that to someone to prove I sent something?

Comment: I think it would also let them spend any funds in your wallet. I believe the private view key is derived from the private spend key, so if someone has your private spend key, then they have complete control of your wallet.

Comment: Never give the private spend key to anyone, it would allow them to spend everything in your wallet. To prove that you spent something to someone, use a transaction proof.